# Android-Dynamically Scrolling Recyclerview Horizontally with Exoplayer current playing position(duration),i.e. Seekbar point current playing position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer, timeline, android-seekbar

I'm working to play multiple videos in Exoplayer and have all setup, I have timelined videos frame in a recyclerview of all videos, I want to scroll Recyclerview with current time duration of Exoplayer for whole time line including touch scroll in horizontal...

For better understanding attaching an image.
[image: Visual for the requirement]